# replacing class name in nested list

Tags: jquery

I have a list and which has classes fa-3x, I am trying to change all the instances of the class `fa-3x` to "fa-lg"  when i click on the "toggle-button-on" and toggle-button-on should change to "toggle-button-off" onClick. How can I do this using jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.nav li ").click(function() {
    $("li").toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass(".fa-3x").css("border", "3px solid red");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="" ng-Click="">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-button-on"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Work </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Music" ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Music</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="faq">
        <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x"></i> 
        <span>Faq</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.find("3a 3x")` should be `.find(".3x-3x")`. You forgot the `.` to select a class, and you left out the `-`.

Comment: Just to clarify are you trying to change all instances of that class or a specific one ?

Comment: all instances of the class fa-3x to fa-lg and change toggle -button-on to toggle-botton-off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just want to operate on the `LI` that the user clicked on, not all of them. So you need to use `$(this)` rather than `$(".li")` to make the changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.nav li ").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg").css("border", "3px solid red");
  });
  $(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
    $(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
    $(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg");
  });
  $(".nav").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
    $(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
    $(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");

  });
});
```

```css
.fa-3x {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.fa-lg {
  background-color: blue;
}
.toggle-button-on {
  color: green;
}
.toggle-button-off {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="" ng-Click="">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-button-on"><i class="fa fa-exchange">toggle</i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x">fa </i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x">fa </i>
        <span>Work </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Music" ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x">fa </i>
        <span>Scenario <br/>Music</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="faq">
        <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x">fa </i> 
        <span>Faq</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change all the instance to fa-lg when the user click on <a class="toggle-button-on">

Comment: You can look at the code I have provided and place it in $("toggle-button-on").click(function(){ code here })

Comment: I've updated the answer. I also put some text into the empty spans so you can see the results and click on the toggle button.

Comment: @Barmar - thank you. one small thing. when i click on "toggle" on and off.. is possible to revert all the instance of fa-lg back to fa-3x when on?

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible. Add another binding for `.toggle-button-off` that does what you want.

Comment: @Bramer- Thank you . i added another binding  for toggle-off http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/q2897rh6/6/.. it didnt seem to revert back on toggle to fa-3x

Comment: I misread `fa-lg` as `fa-1g` when I created my answer. After fixing that, your addition works.

Answer (score 0):

So in this case since you are trying to change all instances you can do:

```
$("toggle-button-on").click(function(){

    $("fa-3x").each(function(){
          $(this).addClass("fa-lg");
           $(this).removeClass("fa-3x");
     }

     $("toggle-button-on").each(function(){
          $(this).addClass("toggle-button-off");
         $(this).removeClass("toggle-button-on");
     }
  }
```

Edit: Fixed typo added onclick event

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors:

in your click event for li selector, you can use $(this) to refer to li object:

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass
```

all classes selectors must have "." first.
Ex.: `find(".3x-3x")`

find method can return a array of objects, so you must use each iterator.
Ex.: `find(".3x-3x").each( function () { $(this).someAction  } );`

With these fixes your code must works.
Hope it helps.